# Display p-values and R in Shiny Plotly graph without overlapping the values

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, ggpubr

I tried to display R and p-values annotations together in a scatter plot where color is differentiated based on species using plotly.

But the text overlapped with each other when it runs in Shiny.

How to adjust the position of the values?

scatter plot shown in shiny:
[image]

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  plotlyOutput("plot")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$plot <- renderPlotly({
    p <- ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Petal.Length)) + list(
      geom_point(aes(color = Species)),
      ggpubr::stat_cor(aes(color = Species), method = "pearson", output.type= "text")
    )
    ggplotly(p) 
  })
  
  
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

simply uses plotly (also is what i expected in shiny):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't see any easy or perfect fix except for extending the `plotly` package to account for the specifics of `ggpubr::stat_cor` or a a refactoring of `ggpubr::stat_cor` to account for how plotly works.

In short, the issue is that `ggpubr::stat_cor` uses `vjust` (Brrr) to shift the labels for the different groups. However, it seems that `vjust` has no effect in `plotly` and hence all labels are placed at their same y position. The same is also true for the `hjust` parameter. But I can't tell whether this is a bug in the `plotly` package or simply a missing feature in `plotly.js`.

A possible fix would be to shift or nudge the x and y positions in `ggplot2` using `stage` and `after_stat`. But I'm afraid that this is not a real robust fix and requires some fiddling to set the right amount of nudging.

```r
library(plotly)
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  plotlyOutput("plot")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$plot <- renderPlotly({
    p <- ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Petal.Length)) +
      list(
        geom_point(aes(color = Species)),
        ggpubr::stat_cor(
          aes(
            x = stage(Sepal.Length, after_stat = min(x) + .5),
            y = stage(Petal.Length, after_stat = y + .5 * seq_along(y)),
            color = Species
          ),
          vjust = .5,
          method = "pearson", output.type = "text"
        )
      )
    ggplotly(p)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
#> 
#> Listening on http://127.0.0.1:5201
```

[image]